# Select every other edge (they share a common vertex)

Tags: mesh

Is it possible to select every other edge in this situation? (see image)

I searched the forums for an answer and read through them, but I couldn't find a similar situation. The *Checker Deselect* doesn't work, I guess because they all connect to a single vert.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

- Use  vertex select mode as indicated by the yellow arrow. Select the perimeter circle by any means including

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd> Click
- Checker deselect every other one
- Last select the center
- If desired switch to edge select mode as indicated by the yellow arrow below
- You may also consider saving your selection with vertex groups

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly